# Python dependecy requires error ( via RPM )2.6->2.7

Tags: rpm

I'm trying to install pyatspi from rpm package ,and met this error:

```
[root@dhcp-128-69 Downloads]# rpm -i pyatspi-2.2.1-1.fc16.noarch.rpm 
warning: pyatspi-2.2.1-1.fc16.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID a82ba4b7: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
       python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by pyatspi-2.2.1-1.fc16.noarch
```

But I had already installed python2.7.10 and link it to command"python":

```
[root@dhcp-128-69 Downloads]# /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.6.6
[root@dhcp-128-69 Downloads]# python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

What's up when I run rpm?

Why it doesn't point to the python2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rpm only examines the rpmdb for dependencies. Since your rpmdb claims to have 2.6, there's no way it can fulfill the 2.7 dependency. Use pip to install the module instead.

Comment: pip will not install the rpmdb dependency (but will install the module). You need to register the installation (by installing a package) in an rpmdb to satisfy the rpm dependency.